# apis trying to get property of non-object laravel

Tags: laravel, api, routes, session-variables

I have an opening function in which I show my session variable which I do it in this way

```
        $id=Session::get('id_player');
        $jugador=Jugador::find($id);
        $dinero=$jugador->saldo;
        echo "<script>alert('".$dinero."')</script>";
```

at that moment it shows me the associated value and everything is fine but when I go to the endpoint of the api, and I put the sentence (without the JS script) it indicates this error ErrorException: Trying to get property 'saldo' of non-object

I try to access the variable as an array ($dinero=$jugador['saldo'];) and it does not work either, it's like if I did not take the session variable since it's the value that does not take

Comment: I assume `Session::get('id_player');` will be your (the players) own id?

Comment: Have you ran a `dd($id)` to confirm it's pulling the correct ID?

Comment: yes I already probe that function and it brings me the id but in the endpoint I put the id and say is null, I probe using a static function and it does not work either, a global variable in the class and it does not work either

Comment: What is the primary field called under Jugador? id or something else?

Comment: id is the primary field

Comment: Why would you need a session variable from an endpoint? HTTP calls are stateless. Doens't store session variables. Please, detail your use case. If you only need to get the logged-in user you could use an `access_token` to identify users.

Comment: I need the id of the user who logs in order to be able to make updates in the BD, but I do not even take the Auth

Answer (score 1):

**About the error**

As the error states. It means the $jugador is null.

to check and assign change

```
$id=Session::get('id_player');
$jugador=Jugador::find($id);
$dinero=$jugador->saldo;
echo "<script>alert('".$dinero."')</script>";
```

to

```
$id=Session::get('id_player');
//findOrFail instead of find method to through error for model not found
if ($jugador = Jugador::find($id)) { 
    $dinero=$jugador->saldo;
    echo "<script>alert('".$dinero."')</script>";
}
```

**Why is session variable null on api?**

Session does not exist default on API. you need to add it to the API middleware. but I wouldn't recommend it. create a new middleware entry named like in this case 'sessions' and add 'start session' to it. like this to

app/Http/Kernel.php

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
       \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
    //add this middleware to the routes you expect sessions to work
    'sessions' => [
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    ]
];
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['sessions']], function () { 
    Route::post('autentificacion_api_GamePlay',
                  'APIGamePlayController@autentificacion'); 
});
```

Comment: Yes indeed the player is null but it is because the session variable is empty in the endpoint, and does not take the associated value in this case is the primary key id

Comment: that's how its suppose to be. If you still want to use API with sessions there it is

Comment: in the kernel i put 

//add this middleware to the routes you expect sessions to work
        'session' => [
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        ],

i put this in the web: 

Route::group(['middleware' => ['sessions']], function () {
    Route::post('autentificacion_api', 'APIController@autentificacion');
});

but a get this error: eflectionException: Class sessions does not exist in file /var/www/html/resexdev/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 767

Comment: but i am curious why would you use sessions on api?

Comment: my bad. i have changed by the time you checked. change  'session' => [ \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, ], to  'sessions' => [ \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, ],

Comment: I keep saying that the session variable is null :(